# NullPointerException on setAdapter()

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a login page with 2 LinearLayouts. 1st contains the login widgets(2 EditTexts and a Button). 2nd contains a ListView that displays public projects. But implementing the ListView I get the following error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
    android:text="testapi@canvasflip.com"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:hint="password"
    android:text="canvas123"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:text="submit"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list1">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends DrawerActivity {

EditText e;
EditText p;
Button s;
String getEmail, getPassword;

ListView mDrawerList, mPublicProjectsList;
protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

ArrayAdapter<String> mPublicProjectsAdapter;

public static HttpClient httpClient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mPublicProjectsList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
    String[] projectItems = {"Project1", "Project2", "Project3", "Project4"};
    mPublicProjectsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, projectItems);
    mPublicProjectsList.setAdapter(mPublicProjectsAdapter);


    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null,false);
    mDrawerLayout.addView(contentView, 0);

    e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    p = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    s = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getEmail = e.getText().toString();
            getPassword = p.getText().toString();
            new HttpHandler().execute();
        }
    });
}



    /*mPublicProjectsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        Intent intent;
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position == 0){
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayBack.class);
                intent.putExtra("playUrl", "http://canvasflip.com/protected/app/playback.php?project=694");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if(position == 1){
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayBack.class);
                intent.putExtra("playUrl", "http://canvasflip.com/protected/app/playback.php?project=696");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if(position == 2){
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayBack.class);
                intent.putExtra("playUrl", "http://canvasflip.com/protected/app/playback.php?project=698");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayBack.class);
                intent.putExtra("playUrl", "http://canvasflip.com/protected/app/playback.php?project=777");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });*/


/*private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] navItems = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7"};
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, navItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
}*/

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class HttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    String url  ="some url";
    String responseStr="";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginId", getEmail));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", getPassword));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
            final String jsonResult = jsonObject.getString("result");
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(jsonResult.equals("success")) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ProjectList.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

DrawerActivity.java:

```
public class DrawerActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
ListView mDrawerList;
protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String mActivityTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();
    /*getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);*/
    addDrawerItems();
    setUpDrawer();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

public void setUpDrawer() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
      public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
          super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
          getSupportActionBar().setTitle("NAVIGATION");
          invalidateOptionsMenu();
      }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };


    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] navItems = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7"};
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, navItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }
}
```

Comment: Pls post complete log

Comment: uncomment  //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT #1:**

I have made a switch (like I have said in the comments) Please try it out to see if it works. Since you are trying to instantiate a view that belongs to Main, you need to inflate it first before referring to it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);+


    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null,false);
    mDrawerLayout.addView(contentView, 0);
        mPublicProjectsList =(ListView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.list1);
    String[] projectItems = {"Project1", "Project2", "Project3", "Project4"};
    mPublicProjectsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, projectItems);
    mPublicProjectsList.setAdapter(mPublicProjectsAdapter);

    e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    p = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    s = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getEmail = e.getText().toString();
            getPassword = p.getText().toString();
            new HttpHandler().execute();
        }
    });
}
```

---

You haven't set a content view for your activity.

After super.onCreate you should call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
```

And only then the rest of your code:

```
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mPublicProjectsList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
    String[] projectItems = {"Project1", "Project2", "Project3", "Project4"};
    mPublicProjectsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, projectItems);
    mPublicProjectsList.setAdapter(mPublicProjectsAdapter);
```

Or at least call after you "inflate" the layout. Because otherwise using "findViewById" won't "find" any view.

Comment: same error even after uncommenting setContentView(). Plus: isn't:
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null,false);
    mDrawerLayout.addView(contentView, 0);
 doing the same thing? why would I need setContentView after inflating the view programatically?

Comment: I see several problems with your code. One of them is you are inflating a view and adding to another (mDrawer) that is null. The problem is that findViewById of mDrawerLayout is null. Besides where is R.id.drawer_layout? The layout where this is should be the setContentView. Then you should move all the code below. Then you can inflate and add to Drawer. (This is a "estimative" on how your code is. If it is wrong, please add to the question the layout where your Drawer is)

Comment: setContentView is not important your view hierarchy will be in memory but not attached as the content of the activity so its not important for the code to work properly at least it doesnt crash your app with null pointer

Comment: and I know that because I tried it several times to check if app crashes....it doesnt ... and setContentView is allways the last step in my onCreate's

Comment: the activity just has no content then:no effect on app stability whatsoever

Comment: @nunofmendes drawer_layout is the Navigation DrawerLayout. What I did was made a separate class for NavigationDrawer and extended it in my MainActivity. I did a separate class for Navigation Drawer so that I can extend that in my every View.

Comment: You don't need setContentView if you create a View and do everything after that. Basically you need a "View v=  new View()"(Inflate) and then v.findViewByID after that. He isn't doing that. He is using the findViewById on the activity itself, which requires a previously set content.

Comment: @IljaKO if I remove the code to display projects list in my MainActivity, the app works fine without any crashes.

Comment: What is the code inside onCreate on DrawerActivity?

Comment: @AmanGrover You are using findViewById in here:  mPublicProjectsList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1); Try to do this after you inflate main. Check the value of this var. Isn't it "null"?

Comment: Lol , I missed this simple fix! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

1st: decomment your setContentView() method so it will be displayed
2nd: Why do you use the android.R:

```
mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

You should allways use your R not androids. I guess here is where the null object comes from... unfortunately most developers dont catch these things or check if they get null back

Comment: when I don't use android.R on the list, it gives me an error saying: My list should contain a ListView whose id is @android:id/list.

Comment: yeah did you define your listview in an xml?

Comment: what do you think should the android.R give you? nothing it just returns a nulkl object...check it out if you dont believe me ;)

Comment: I defined the ListView in the activity_main.xml, should I define a completely new xml for the different ListViews in my activity?

Answer (score 0):

You have forget to  `setContentView ();`
Check below Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layour.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do setContentView() first, which will create the Views and then you should find them using findViewById() and work on them. Please check the below code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mPublicProjectsList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
    String[] projectItems = {"Project1", "Project2", "Project3", "Project4"};
    mPublicProjectsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, projectItems);
    mPublicProjectsList.setAdapter(mPublicProjectsAdapter);


    e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    p = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    s = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getEmail = e.getText().toString();
            getPassword = p.getText().toString();
            new HttpHandler().execute();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I had provided the exact same solution (as accepted) much before. Why has it not been upvoted or accepted?